# Login credential issue using NSURL Methods

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have an webservices url which appends with password. When I run the application by giving correct password, the application is running and at the same time when I run the app with wrong credentials. the app is running, I didn't have an idea to get rid out of the issue. My code is here:

```
     NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"password=%@",[password text]];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myexample.com/Accountservice/Secure/ValidateAccess?password=abcd&type=1"]];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLRequest *request1 = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
        if(!connection){
            NSLog(@"connection failed");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"connection succeeded");
        }
```

If I gave 'abcd' as password connection is successfully is displaying. If I gave wrong password connection successfully is displaying. How can I solve the issue? If I gave wrong password need to display an alert.

Comment: accesscode='abcd'&type='1'

Comment: just they are appended to that url as it is webservices url...

Comment: POST here doesnt do anything if you are passing the value in the url!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be with the url you are using

1. Fire the url in the browser and see what it returnes
2. try add the url params with single quotes accesscode='abcd'

It is not a good practice to pass the credentials via this way.
You could use POST method with some valid encryption to prevent the security issues that can occur

**SOLUTION**
Try this

```
  NSString *urlString=@"http://myexample.com/Accountservice/Secure/ValidateAccess?";
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",userNameTextField.text,passwordTextField.text];
    NSData *postData=[post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection *connection0= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection0 start];
```

Comment: I am getting issues at post method, can you check my code once...?

Comment: @sudheerchekuri : Yeah that is what i said you are using post method but what you are posting there? nothing!!!.Please go through the sample i provided you can see the data is added as Http body and that will get posted

Comment: I will send code through paste bin.Can you check it once as it is urgent requirement for me.

Comment: I am getting errors as responseData not found on object of type.. like that.. can you help me to solve the issue..

Comment: Exception: -[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ccd4e0 error is showing.

Comment: where it hits?error says  that you are looking for length somewhere in code of object which is an NSURL.

Comment: Hi, When I run the application, for every password login failed alert which is in catch method and above error is showing... can u check it once http://pastebin.com/2zHjvbxN

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26001/discussion-between-sudheer-chekuri-and-lithu-t-v)

Answer (score 1):

This control structure here is the problem:

```
if(!connection){
    NSLog(@"connection failed");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"connection succeeded");
}
```

This doesn't check for a bad connection, this checks whether or not the connection object is equal to 0 (nil).  Obviously, having initialized it on the line above, the else statement will always log, giving you the false impression that your connection had succeeded.  You should become the connection's [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), and respond to the appropriate delegate methods instead.